# In haskell how to convert a String list into with a int list inside

Tags: haskell

In Haskell I have this list:

```
["1 2","3 4"]
```

And I need to convert it to this form:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

After this sum the values inside the list:

```
[3,7]
```

Any idea how I can do it?

I think that I can do it with map and sum, but I can't find the way.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english

Comment: You've done an excellent job of breaking the problem down into some smaller steps. Take a look at chepner's answer for what to do next. Each of those steps can be its own function, more or less.

Comment: Simple example
`fmap (sum . fmap (read @Int) . words) ["1 2", "3 4"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by writing a function `foo :: String -> [Int]`:

```
> foo "1 2"
[1,2]
> foo "3 4"
[3,4]
```

One you have that, you just need a sequence of `map` operation: mapping `foo` over your input gives your list of lists of integers, then mapping sum over that result gives you your list of integers.